# In this sentence, to whom 自分 refers?

Tags: grammar

I want to say

> It is unfair to judge other people based on our own belief (not necessarily religious belief).

I have two options:

- Ａ:　私たちの信仰で、他の人を判断するのは不正である。
- B:　自分の信仰で、他の人を判断するのは不正である。

I want to use B but I am not sure whether 自分 refers to us (the speaker) rather than the other people (object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word "our", from "our believe" in the original English sentence, is actually referring to in general, right? If I understand correctly, you are making a philosophical statement that applies to anyone.

If so, 自分 would be more appropriate.

Also, while I think your sentence would be understandable by a Japanese person, I am not sure if it is completely natural. I think this might be more natural, and more general since you said it doesn't have to be just religious belief:

> 自分の価値観だけで他人を判断してはいけません

Answer (score 1):

自分 usually means oneself and doesn't refer to us. However 自分たち means 私たち and it refers to us.